# How do I import extensions to an ES6/Typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, polyline, es6-modules

I'm trying to convert a simple Javascript prototype written in a single .html file with embedded `<script>` tags to a module compiled with Typescript.

It's using Leaflet which I was happily able to get installed via

```
npm install leaflet

npm install --save @types/leaflet
```

importing via

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
```

and using via eg.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-43.4175044, 172.185657], 8);
```

However I also want to use this https://rawgit.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded/master/Polyline.encoded.js Javascript file which provides some extensions to the main Leaflet L object.

I've tried importing this via

```
import 'https://rawgit.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded/master/Polyline.encoded.js'
```

However when I attempt to use it eg.

```
 var coordinates = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(encoded).getLatLngs();
```

I get the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'fromEncoded' does not exist on type 'typeof Polyline'.
```

How can I get this working? Is it just a matter of providing types support for these extensions? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: well, find the @types package for polyline and import it, that should do the trick.

Comment: @toskv if there are no types packages available, what's the easiest way to create one myself? The 'fromEncoded' method is actually the only one I need.

Comment: just write it in a .d.ts file in your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tricky due to how [polyline-encoded](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded) works: this plugin extends `Leaflet`. So if we want it to work exactly as in JavaScript, we need to extend the leaflet types and its 1550 lines! Even more problematic, every time we want to update `Leaflet`, we need to check whether its types have been updated and merge them with the `polyline-encoded` types!

Another potential issue: in your code, `Leaflet` is used in a ES6 module but `polyline-encoded` is based on an IIFE that changes the current `Leaflet` object `L`, mixing old and new JavaScript ways. I'm curious to know if it works.

Anyway, a safer option that I see *(but didn't test yet)*:

- Define new types → see `Leaflet.encoded.d.ts` below, to add to your project.
- Force-cast `L` as the extended type defined in `Leaflet.encoded.d.ts`: `Lx.L;`.
- Use `Lx` instead of `L` for every use of the `polyline-encoded` extensions.

Your code adapted:

```js
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'https://rawgit.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded/master/Polyline.encoded.js';

const Lx = L as any as Lx.L;

const map = L.map('map').setView([-43.4175044, 172.185657], 8);

const coordinates = Lx.Polyline.fromEncoded('...').getLatLngs();
```

`Leaflet.encoded.d.ts`:

```js
// Type definitions for Leaflet polyline-encoded 0.0.8
// Project: https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded
// Definitions by: Romain Deneau <https://github.com/rdeneau>
// TypeScript Version: 2.5

import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet';

export as namespace Lx;

export interface L {
    PolylineUtil: PolylineUtil;
    Polyline: Polyline;
    Polygon: Polygon;
}

// -- PolylineUtil plugin ---------------------------------

export interface PolylineUtilOptions {
    precision: number;
    factor: number;
    dimension: number;
}

export type LatLngTuple = [number, number];

export interface PolylineUtil {
    /**
     * Decode the string `encoded` to an array of `[lat, lng]`-arrays.
     */
    decode(encoded: string, options?: number|PolylineUtilOptions): LatLngTuple[];

    /**
     * Encode an array of `L.LatLng` objects, or an array of arrays.
     */
    encode(points: Leaflet.LatLng[]|LatLngTuple[], options?: number|PolylineUtilOptions): string;
}

// -- Polyline/Polygon extensions -------------------------

export class Polyline extends Leaflet.Polyline {
    /**
     * Return an encoded string for the current Polyline.
     */
    encodePath(): string;

    /**
     * Construct a new `L.Polyline` from a string, with optional `options` object.
     * Backslashes in strings should be properly escaped.
     */
    fromEncoded(encoded: string, options?: Leaflet.PolylineOptions): Leaflet.Polyline;
}

export class Polygon extends Leaflet.Polygon {
    /**
     * Return an encoded string for the current Polygon.
     */
    encodePath(): string;

    /**
     * Construct a new `L.Polygon` from a string, with optional `options` object.
     * Backslashes in strings should be properly escaped.
     */
    fromEncoded(encoded: string, options?: Leaflet.PolylineOptions): Leaflet.Polygon;
}
```

If it's working, this types can even be shared, submitting them to the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thankyou! I'd never have worked out that IIFE step myself.